# SQL if no rows are returned do this

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a select statement and I want to say if this select statement does not return any rows then put a '' in every cell. How do I do this?

Comment: Put a '' in ever cell of what? An SSRS report? An Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: I have 2 units. 1 has data, and 1 does not. I want to show the 1 units data but only show blanks for all the other units data that has no data. If that makes any sense?

Comment: yes its going to be for an SSRS report

Comment: It might make more sense if we could see your code and some sample data.

Comment: there we go there is the query up top

Comment: Left outer join might be want you want?  I'm trying to understand what's meant here.

Comment: Bascially there is no data for unit e2499 in table IUA but there is for unit E2546 and I need to return both units evne if unit r2499 has no data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're still not getting all the rows you want.  True?  I think @Joe Sefanelli provides an important part to your solution, and then mentions that you need to change INNER to LEFT joins.

So, you say you want to display all units in your units list.  And, if there's no data for a unit, then display the unit and blanks for the data that doesn't exist.

Here's a possible solution.  Change your FROM clause to the following:

```
FROM  [dbo].[Unit] u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[IUA] i
    JOIN [dbo].[Reports] r ON r.[Report_ID] = i.[Report_ID]
    JOIN [dbo].[State] s ON i.[St_ID] = s.[St_Id]
    WHERE r.[Account] = [dbo].[fn_Get_PortalUser_AccountNumber](11-11)
        AND r.[Rpt_Period] = '2126'
        AND r.[RptName] = 'tfd'
        AND r.[Type] = 'h'    
    ) ir ON ir.[Unit_ID] = u.[Unit_ID]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[UnitType] ut ON u.[UnitType] = ut.[UnitType]
WHERE u.[Unit] IN (SELECT [VALUE] 
               FROM dbo.udf_GenerateVarcharTableFromStringList(@Units, ','))
;
```

With this change you will get a list of units that are in the @Units list.  The left outer joins will include data associated with each unit, but will not exclude units if there is no associated data.

Comment: This actually returns all the report periods which would not work becasue I am trying to get only 2126. There is data for the unit in different report periods but not this report period. If I move this into the where clause it still returns no rows again.

Comment: New version that uses derived table to produce data from [IUA], [Reports] and [STATE].  Then, joins to other tables.

Comment: Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 36
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with uniqueidentifier
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
The column 'Report_ID' was specified multiple times for 'ir'.

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
The multi-part identifier "s.FuelRate" could not be bound.

Comment: For the Msg 206 you will need to change the `SELECT *` to `SELECT` with a list of columns that are referenced elsewhere in the query.  This will avoid duplication that is indicated.  For Msg 4104, change your SELECT clause to use ir instead of i or s.  This will reference the derived table alias.

Comment: in my OP that is how I changed it. It now says Unit_Id is invalid column?

Comment: Add `i.[unit_id],` to the derived table `LEFT OUTER JOIN  
        ( 
        SELECT i.[unit_id],
            i.[Non_Toll],`

Comment: I didnt figure out this way of doing it but you definitely helped me with finding the answer THANKS!!!

Answer (score 8):

```
select a, b, c from t
if @@rowcount = 0
    select '' as a, '' as b, '' as c
```

But make sure you understand that `''` may have a different datatype than columns `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this -

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'x' FROM <TABLE> .... )
BEGIN
    -- Your logic goes here
END
```

Comment: The issue is I could have 1 unit that shows data and 1 unit that doesn't show data thus this would only show that one units data but I want both units to show....

Comment: @anicolais - For your second unit where you want to show blank data, see answer from tenfour. Would that help?

Comment: there is the initial query in OP

Answer (score 4):

Put your blank row select at the bottom of a union

```
select x.JobName , x.Description
from MasterJobList x
where x.IsCycleJob = 1 

union all

select "" , "" 
from MasterJobList x
where not exists
    (
    select 1
    from MasterJobList x
    where x.IsCycleJob = 1 
    )
```

Comment: Like this a lot, works great for me and doesn't need to be wrapped in a function.  Yay.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the posted code, I think you're looking to blank out the columns from the UnitType table as that's the only one you're left-joining to. In that case use

```
ISNULL(ut.[Description], '')  AS UnitType
```

Comment: This still returns no rows for me if I say u.number = 'e2499' it just gives no rows. I need it to give the unit number but no data.

Comment: Then some of your current INNER joins need to be LEFT joins instead, depending on which table(s) you're not finding a matching row in. Then use ISNULL as in my answer to blank those columns as well.

Comment: The table that doesnt have a match row in is IUA so i'm not sure exaclty what I would do here as most have conversion errors when doing ISNULL

Comment: ISNULL will return a column of the same datatype as the expression you are testing. Some conversion may be necessary to return '' in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 isnull(max(col2),' ') as noNullCol from table1 where col1='x'
```

max returns a `null` where not have rows then `isnull` function returns `' '` instead a `null` value

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example I use for a single column - it's easy and only produces a blank row if there are no matches in the dataset.

```
select Company from customer where customer=@Company
union
select '' where not exists (select 1 from customer where customer=@Company)
```

This creates a row of blank(s) when there are no matches.