# Permissions stored as true/false, retrieve a single row XOR'ed

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

It was difficult to find a way to word this question, but basically what I am trying to do is query out a set of permission values from a table that represents permissions present as boolean's (bit) where they are either true or false.

However Users can either have permissions directly, or via a role that they are in, so it is possible to be a user with no permission to delete someone elses comment but be in a role that allows deleting someone elses comment.

So I would like to analyze all the users permissions, and return true if it is set anywhere, and false if it is not.  So a true value will override all false values.

Here is the SQL for the permissions table,

```
CREATE TABLE [xyz].[CommentPermissions](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Identifier] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[IdentifierType] [int] NOT NULL,
[CanEditPermissions] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
[CanDeleteContainer] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
[CanEditOthersComments] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
[CanDeleteOthersComments] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
[CanPostComments] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
[CanBlockReplies] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
[CanReplyToOthers] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((1)),
[CanDeleteOwnComments] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((1)),
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Now looking at that, Identifier is a guid that represents either a User or a Role, Which is indicated by IdentifierType which is 0 for user or 1 for role.

Now I've written a stored procedure to join it up so I get all the users permissions, including roles they are in,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [xyz].[comments.getUserPermissions]
@UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT 
        cp.CanEditPermissions,
        cp.CanDeleteContainer,
        cp.CanEditOthersComments,
        cp.CanDeleteOthersComments,
        cp.CanPostComments,
        cp.CanBlockReplies,
        cp.CanReplyToOthers,
        cp.CanDeleteOwnComments
        FROM [xyz].[CommentPermissions] as cp 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [security].[Roles] as r on cp.Identifier = r.Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [security].[UsersInRoles] as ur on r.Id = ur.RoleId
        WHERE ur.UserId = @UserId or (cp.Identifier = @UserId AND cp.IdentifierType = 0)
RETURN 0
```

So what this does it it joins Identifier on the Roles table and the UsersInRoles table where the UsersInRoles table's UserId is equal to the UserId Parameter passed to the stored parameter,  then I filter where ur.UserId is equal to the parameter or  the permissions identifier is equal to the user type if the IdentifierType is 0.

This effectively gives me back all the permissions the user has on the comment system, but...

Now how would I go about xoring the rows together (while trying to avoid using a cursor)..

What I get back at the moment looks like this,

[image]

What I want to happen is I want one row back where all of these rows are basically merged together so that 1's override 0's.  However if no rows come back I want to return 1 row of all 0's.

**Update:-----------------** 
I have a working solution now, but I'll leave this open in case someone knows a better way to do this, but here's the updated stored procedure.

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT      
CONVERT(BIT, MAX(CONVERT(tinyint, cp.CanEditPermissions))) as 'CanEditPermissions',
CONVERT(BIT, MAX(CONVERT(tinyint, cp.CanDeleteContainer))) as 'CanDeleteContainer',
CONVERT(BIT, MAX(CONVERT(tinyint, cp.CanEditOthersComments))) as 'CanEditOthersComments',
CONVERT(BIT, MAX(CONVERT(tinyint, cp.CanDeleteOthersComments))) as 'CanDeleteOthersComments',
CONVERT(BIT, MAX(CONVERT(tinyint, cp.CanPostComments))) as 'CanPostComments',
CONVERT(BIT, MAX(CONVERT(tinyint, cp.CanBlockReplies))) as  'CanBlockReplies',
CONVERT(BIT, MAX(CONVERT(tinyint, cp.CanReplyToOthers))) as 'CanReplyToOthers',
CONVERT(BIT, MAX(CONVERT(tinyint, cp.CanDeleteOwnComments))) as 'CanDeleteOwnComments'
FROM [xyz].[CommentPermissions] as cp 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [security].[Roles] as r on cp.Identifier = r.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN [security].[UsersInRoles] as ur on r.Id = ur.RoleId
WHERE (ur.UserId = @UserId or (cp.Identifier = @UserId AND cp.IdentifierType = 0)) or 1 = 1
```

Comment: So why dont you return just the first row and use one of the answers in this thread for no row returned situation.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702576/sql-if-no-rows-are-returned-do-this

Comment: Because the 2nd row could have permissions set the first row doesn't. E.g let's say the first row has 0 for CanEditPermissions but the 2nd row has 1.  In such a case I need everything from the first row except the first column and the 1st column from the 2nd row.